# Get data from foreign key in blade

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I don't know how to get the data from this foreign key. I have followed all steps from the documentation, but I still don't know what needs to be done.

This is my product model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function sector(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Sector');
    }
    public function sale(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Sale');
    }
}
```

This is my Sector Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sector extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'products_id';

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

This is my controller (only index):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Sector;
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       $products = Product::all();
       return view('worker.index', compact('products'));
    }
```

And this is my view (only the interested part):

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{$product->name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{$product->codice_prodotto}}</p>

        {{-- <p class="card-text">{{$product->sectors->products_id}}</p> i've tried this and that gets' me this error
        Trying to get property 'products_id' of non-object         --}}

        {{-- <p class="card-text">{{$product->sectors['products_id']}}</p> i've tried this and that get's me this error
        Trying to access array offset on value of type null

        --}}
```

Comment: I think that code inside blade is typo try  something like this ```{{$product->sector->products_id}}```

Comment: nope the name of the table is sectors it's correct like that but still won't work

Comment: Do all of your products have sectors?

Comment: @areg yes every product have a sectors the product_id is the id of the product and that is the primary key of the sectors table

Comment: Can you try to wrap your p tags in `@if($product->sectors)` and see what happens?

Comment: @areg They don't show up

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
{{$product->sectors->products_id}}
```

**sectors** must be **sector** the same of function name

```
{{$product->sector->products_id}}
```

Something else, the default of `foreign_key` must be `product_id` not `products_id`,
so you have to define it in the relation

```
 public function sector(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Sector','products_id');
    }
```